# How does moderation work on localized Stack Overflow sites?

Tags: support, moderator-election

I'm participating in the main Stack Overflow site as well as in its [Portuguese version](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). Since there isn't any meta site for the localized Stack Overflow sites and in the moderator election there isn't any mention of the languages that the candidates speak, how is moderation done on those sites?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each localized Stack Overflow site works as its own, independent site.

Each site *does* have its own associated Meta (for example, the Meta site for SO.PT is here: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/), and each site has their own moderators (for example, PT.SO is moderated by [this fine crew](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)). Elections are periodically run on localized SO sites, just like they are run on English SO.

The English Stack Overflow moderators do not moderate any of the localized sites, and this election has nothing to do with any other sites.

Comment: I had no idea that meta existed, since the button to that meta has just now appeared in my profile when I entered this link. Might be something that needs to be revisited in Stack Overflow's UX. Thank you, Cody

Comment: @Daniel On any site, you should be able to click the Stack Exchange button at the far right of the top bar. That will show a drop-down menu showing the site you're currently on and its associated Meta. If you try it on PT.SO, you should see it shows that site's Meta.

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima let me support what Cody just said with a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IRIa.png

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima the meta profile is not automatically created until the user visits the meta site for the first time.

Comment: @AndrewT.I guess now it makes sense why the button never showed up before. I found this meta while fiddling around with the links in the site's footer. I find these metas fairly hidden, I don't know if by design